# Netezza SQL replace function?

Tags: netezza

Is there `replace` function in Netezza? If not, what is the alternative way to achieve?

eg.

```
replace('abc','a','1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Netezza provides a TRANSLATE function out of the box, a[s documented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_char_funcs.html?lang=en).

Netezza also includes a REPLACE function in the SQL Extension Toolkit, [as documented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_replace.html), which must be enabled by an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Netezza has a bunch of extended functions. In our company, they are installed under TOOLKIT.SQLEXT, so your query will be like this:

```
SELECT TOOLKIT.SQLEXT.REPLACE('abc', 'a', '1') AS STR;
```

Result:

```
STR
1bc
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `REPLACE` cannot be fully replaced by `TRANSLATE`. You can check this answer for `REPLACE` alternative:
[How to replace escape character in Netezza column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331723/how-to-replace-escape-character-in-netezza-column/44391282#44391282)