# How to replace escape character in Netezza column

Tags: netezza

I am trying to replace escape character in Netezza column, but it is not properly replacing. 
Please help me some one on this.

```
select replace('replaces\tring','\','\\\\');
```

I need output as `replaces\\\\tring`. Below is the error message i am getting...

> ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  Function 'REPLACE(UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN)'
>   does not exist    Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given
>   argument types    You may need to add explicit typecasts

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried this and its giving me your desired output. What does it give you?

Comment: i just edited and added the error message in question, please see and give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `REPLACE` function needs to be installed (which is not by default). There is another function which is called `TRANSLATE` which can be used in a limited way instead of `REPLACE` but unfortunately won't fit in your situation.

You can use the below query instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, 1, INSTR(x, '\') - 1) || '\\\\' || SUBSTRING(x, INSTR(x, '\') + LENGTH('\')) FROM 
(SELECT 'replaces\tring' AS x) t
```

- `\` passed to `INSTR` and `LENGTH` is the string to be replaced. Note that they occur in three positions.
- `\\\\` in the middle is the replacement string.
- `replaces\tring` is the string to search in.

Check the below example for replace **love** with **like** in **I love Netezza**:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, 1, INSTR(x, 'love') - 1) || 'like' || SUBSTRING(x, INSTR(x, 'love') + LENGTH('love')) FROM 
(SELECT 'I love Netezza' AS x) t
```

Answer (score 0):

That particular function is part of the "SQL Extensions toolkit" and on our system it is placed in the ADMIN schema of the SQLEXT database. All users have been granted execute access to that schema. Furthermore the database.schema have been placed in the path (the DBA's did it globally, but you can issue a "set PATH=..." in your session if need be)

our path is:

```
select current_path;

CURRENT_PATH
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLEXT.ADMIN,INZA.INZA,NZA.INZA,NZM.INZA,NZMSG.INZA,NZR.INZA,NZRC.INZA,SYNCHDB.ADMIN
```

and as you can see the SQLEXT is at the beginning...